# Doubts of committing kufr

Tags: practical-islam, kufr

I recently reverted to Islam after leaving for a few years and I’m trying my best to be a good Muslim but I keep getting scared that I did something that is kufr and I’m now out of the fold of Islam and I have to repeat my conversion process and repent. It’s happening for weeks, I’ve said the shahada several times. For example, yesterday I watched a video about Islam and the scholar said something about people acting like saying shahada is so difficult so I laughed but then I got scared that I might’ve mocked a part of Islam. Can someone let me know if this is kufr or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Allah is most forgiving most merciful."(5:74)
Come on ,don't worry, Allah knows best what is in your heart and He knows your efforts that you do everyday for him.

Comment: No ,you are not a bad muslim, you are trying so hard to keep allah happy ,this is the sign that you are not a bad muslim .Stop worrying too much, Allah wants ease for you,you didn't do wrong,it was just thought made by shaitan to deceive you so whenever these thoughts come to your mind start thinking about something else.